# Store uploaded document in database using Entity Framework (via MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, file-upload

Does anyone have an example of how to store an uploaded document (whether Word or PDF, *etc*.) in a SQL Server 2008 DB using the Entity Framework?

I think I've figured out the file upload part (see code below) although I'm open to constructive comments.

I used to do a lot of document-storing in older DBs, and as SQL Server 2008 has new data types, can someone suggest which I should be using for my uploaded document (is it still Image)?

Furthermore, as you can see from my code, if I have the uploaded document as a byte array (or please suggest otherwise) how do I pass this to my entity?

Here's what I have so far:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
{
    if (fileUpload == null) return View();

    if (fileUpload.ContentLength == 0) return View();

    // not sure whether this is useful or the method below this
    var reader = new StreamReader(fileUpload.InputStream);

    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        var hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0) continue;
        var savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));

        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);

        var curFile = System.IO.File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
        var fileLength = curFile.Length;

        var tempFile = new byte[fileLength];
        curFile.Read(tempFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileLength));

        var jobFile = new JobFile
                              {
                                  UploadDate = DateTime.Now,
                                  UploadedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                                  FileName = savedFileName,
                                  ContentType = hpf.ContentType
                              };
        jobFile.FileData = 

        _jobFileRepository.Save();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have FileData as type binary.

jobFile.FileData = tempFile.ToArray();

Comment: That seems pretty straightforward - thanks. However, my problem now is how do I map an Image field in my database to my entity model? Image doesn't appear to be a valid option in the drop-down for Data Type in the Properties window (in Visual Studio). If I go into Management Studio and change the Data Type to Image and then update my model I get an error message saying that the mapping is not valid.